# Only allow administrators and editors to access wp-admin

Tags: wp-admin, user-roles, user-access

I am trying to restrict access to wp-admin so that only administrators and editors are allowed. At the moment I am using this function:

```
function restrict_admin(){
    //if not administrator, kill WordPress execution and provide a message
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        wp_die( __('You are not allowed to access this part of the site') );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'restrict_admin', 1 );
```

But this does the job only for administrator; editors are not allowed to access this part of the site. What can I do?

Comment: What is different from the default behavior of Wordpress and what you want to implement exactly

Comment: I want that editors could view information from wp-admin, but not having permission to change it.

Comment: Seems like the default permission system built-into Wordpress should handle a situation like this. There already is a tested and proven plug-in that allows you adjust the roles: http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/user-role-editor and a description of the default roles: http://en.support.wordpress.com/user-roles/#changing-user-roles just took my until now to realize you didn't write the code you posted.  You can also add new roles: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/ and efine the exact permissins you want.

Comment: I tested the code above and both Editors and Administrators are able to access the DashBoard whereas simple users are not.

Answer (score 3):

You're correct in that you should be checking for a capability.  However, manage options is only given to administrators by default.  You should check against a capability that both editors and administrators have such as delete_others_posts.

```
function restrict_admin(){
//if not administrator, kill WordPress execution and provide a message
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'delete_others_posts' ) ) {
        wp_die( __('You are not allowed to access this part of the site') );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'restrict_admin', 1 );
```

See [roles and capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Editor) from the codex.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this :

```
<?php if( current_user_can('editor') || current_user_can('administrator') ) {  ?> 
    // stuff here for admins or editors
<?php } ?>
```

For detailed reference check this another [thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131814/if-current-user-is-admin-or-editor) on stack.

Thanks

Comment: [From the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can), "Passing role names to current_user_can() is discouraged as this is not guaranteed to work correctly"

Answer (score 0):

For me, since per Codex Passing role names to current_user_can() is discouraged as this is not guaranteed to work correctly (see [#22624](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22624)), best option is something like this.

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$allowed_roles = array('administrator','editor');

if(array_intersect($allowed_roles, $user->roles)){
    //user have $allowed_roles
}
```