# If the current user is an administrator or editor

Tags: users, user-roles

How can I check to see if the current logged-in user is an administrator or an editor?

I know how to do each individually:

```
<?php if(current_user_can('editor')) { ?> 
    <!-- Stuff here for editors -->
<?php } ?>

<?php if(current_user_can('administrator')) { ?>
    <!-- Stuff here for administrators -->
<?php } ?>
```

But how do I work those in together? I.e., the user is an administrator or editor?

Comment: `if( current_user_can('editor') || current_user_can('administrator') )`

Answer (score 315, accepted):

First answer, not WordPress-related because it is just only PHP: Use the logic "OR" operator:

```
<?php if( current_user_can('editor') || current_user_can('administrator') ) {  ?>
    // Stuff here for administrators or editors
<?php } ?>
```

If you want to check more than two roles, you can check if the roles of the current user is inside an array of roles, something like:

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$allowed_roles = array('editor', 'administrator', 'author');
<?php if( array_intersect($allowed_roles, $user->roles ) ) {  ?>
   // Stuff here for allowed roles
<?php } ?>
```

However, [`current_user_can`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) can be used not only with users' role name, but also with capabilities.

So, once both editors and administrators can edit pages, your life can be easier checking for those capabilities:

```
<?php if( current_user_can('edit_others_pages') ) {  ?>
    // Stuff here for user roles that can edit pages: editors and administrators
<?php } ?>
```

Have a look [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/) for more information on capabilities.

Comment: do you need to check if `is_logged_in();` ?

Comment: @RobBenz no, in any of the cases. Because `current_user_can()` always returns false if the user is not logged in, and `wp_get_current_user()` will return an user without any role if the user is not logged in, so the `array_intersect()` will always be false.

Comment: In the PHPDoc of the `current_user_can()` function, we can see the line "_While checking against particular roles in place of a capability is supported in part, this practice is discouraged as it may produce unreliable results_". So I think it would be better to avoid using roles while checking for a user's capability :-)

Comment: When I use the `array_intersect` method, I get a PHP warning in our server error log saying `array_intersect(): Argument #2 is not an array`. Is this because the user(s) it's checking only have one Role?

Comment: @Garconis normally it should be an array. For some reason it seems for you is not an array. `array_intersect($allowed_roles, (array)$user->roles )` will work with no issues.

Comment: I'd advise against checking against roles... and rather against capabilities. It's easier to remove or add a capability to a set of roles... it's more explicit. `current_user_can('edit_orderform')` for example... maybe a Salesrep should ONLY be able to edit the order form... but not have the rights to add content. Explicitly granting that capability is a more explicit permissions structure than what role a user is. People wear multiple hats in larger organizations. you can have subscribers that have more access than just reading.

Comment: +1 not sure why people are raging againt using `current_user_can` for checking roles. It is documented in the API as legitimate usage, end of story. Is it smart to do? depends on the context

Answer (score 21):

First, `current_user_can()` should not be used to check a user's role - it should be used to check if a user has a specific *capability*.

Second, rather than being concerned with the user's role but instead focusing on capabilities, you don't have to bother with doing things like the problem asked about in the original question (which is checking if the user is an administrator OR an editor).  Instead, if `current_user_can()` was being used as intended, which is to check for a user's capabilities, **not** their role, you wouldn't need the conditional check to contain an "or" (||) test.  For example:

`if ( current_user_can( 'edit_pages' ) ) { ...`

edit_pages is a capability of both administrator and editor roles, but not any lower roles such as authors.  This is how `current_user_can()` was intended to be used.

Comment: **Please note**: High level WP devs agree with this answer. You should try to avoid role checking as much as possible, use capabilties. I'm currently working on a project with multiple roles that only have the 'read' cap. The only solution is role checking for me. Sorry, I can't find the link, it was an open discussion on the WP Github.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, IMO. `current_user_can` should generally be used for capabilities, not roles.

Comment: +1 to this, avoid checking roles via `current_user_can()`. If you want to check roles by key then perform a role check instead of a cap check :)

Comment: What is the proper function then, for checking user roles explicitly & safely? It seems, it's a bit hard to find that (if exists). @Bjorn

Comment: @Viktor Borítás There are multiple valid solutions on this page. But only use them if `current_user_can()` is not an option. Also, my comment is more security based. For example, if you want to restrict content for specific users in most cases a capability check is sufficient for this task.

Comment: It's preferable to use capabilities "to protect" operations because those are more flexible, easier to filter, and granularly assign to users. But if the question one is looking for an answer to is _"Is the current user an editor?"_ then using `current_user_can` is **perfectly fine**, actually, that's exactly the way one should use.

Comment: @gmazzap - actually, using `current_user_can()` for checking a role is not "perfectly fine." If it were, why would the function's documentation need to say, "this practice is discouraged as it may produce unreliable results." Just because something "works" does not make it a good or acceptable practice. The internet is already full of bad coding practices passed off as acceptable. Please don't add to it.

Comment: @butlerblog you know Codex is written by contributors? I'm coding for WordPress for 16 years, and with the number of mistakes I found in Codex in these years I could write a book. That said, that's not a mistake but is written poorly. As I already wrote, the practice is discouraged to answer the question: _"is the current user allowed to do X?"_ because if that's what you need to answer checking role _will_ produce unreliable results. *But* if you want to answer the question _"Has this user the role X?"_, which is a different question, then `current_user_can()` is the **correct** way to go.

Comment: I'm not referring to the codex. Not only is the codex technically deprecated, what we're talking about comes directly from the inline documentation in Core, and is in the developer documentation, which has considerably more oversight than codex.  Additionally, encouraging this function to be used that way leads to other bad habits in the improper use of roles vs capabilities, examples of which abound across the webernet. You're welcome to your opinion, but we're going to have to agree to disagree.

Comment: I'm sorry, if this is technically deprecated, what is the way you use in WordPress to check if a user has a role? @butlerblog
Note that I'm not asking what is the way to check if a user is authorized to perform an operation, but - again- to check if an user has a role or not.

Comment: When I said "technically deprecated", I was referring specifically to your reference to codex. Using `current_user_can()` is not deprecated - it *never* was supposed to be used to check a role - it has been that way since WP 2.0, and it's noted inline and in the dev docs. To check if a user has a role (which there is almost no good reason to do), it's an array in the object: `$user->roles`.  For ex: `in_array( 'some_role', $user->roles );`  But checking for roles leads to bad habits. Roles are intended to bulk assign a group of capabilities to a user, it is capability that should be checked.

Answer (score 5):

As @butlerblog reply stated, **you should not use current_user_can to check against a role**

This notice is specifically added in the PHP documentation of `has_cap` function which is called by `current_user_can`

> While checking against a role in place of a capability is supported in part, this practice is discouraged as it may produce unreliable results.

The ***CORRECT*** way to do this is to get the user and check the `$user->roles`, like this:

```
if( ! function_exists( 'current_user_has_role' ) ){
    function current_user_has_role( $role ) {

        $user = get_userdata( get_current_user_id() );
        if( ! $user || ! $user->roles ){
            return false;
        }

        if( is_array( $role ) ){
            return array_intersect( $role, (array) $user->roles ) ? true : false;
        }

        return in_array( $role, (array) $user->roles );
    }
}
```

Here's some helper functions I use to do this (as sometimes i don't want just current user):

```
if( ! function_exists( 'current_user_has_role' ) ){
    function current_user_has_role( $role ){
        return user_has_role_by_user_id( get_current_user_id(), $role );
    }
}

if( ! function_exists( 'get_user_roles_by_user_id' ) ){
    function get_user_roles_by_user_id( $user_id ) {
        $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
        return empty( $user ) ? array() : $user->roles;
    }
}

if( ! function_exists( 'user_has_role_by_user_id' ) ){
    function user_has_role_by_user_id( $user_id, $role ) {

        $user_roles = get_user_roles_by_user_id( $user_id );

        if( is_array( $role ) ){
            return array_intersect( $role, $user_roles ) ? true : false;
        }

        return in_array( $role, $user_roles );
    }
}
```

Then you can just do this:

`current_user_has_role( 'editor' );`

or

`current_user_has_role( array( 'editor', 'administrator' ) );`

Comment: Access low-level properties is never a good idea in WP, surely is not the _correct_ way.  If the question one is looking for an answer to is _"Is the current user an editor?"_ then using `current_user_can` is perfectly fine, actually, that's exactly the way to go. The fact that is preferable to use capabilities to "protect" operations is a different topic. Knowing the role of a user might be a legitimate thing, and in that case, `current_user_can` is perfectly fine to use.

Comment: @gmazzap then why would it specifically say "While checking against particular roles in place of a capability is supported in part, this practice is discouraged as it may produce unreliable results." on `current_user_can` documentation page.  Seems the documentation and your comment are contradicting, although I do understand what you're saying.  With that said though, `$roles` is a public property on `WP_User` object and has been since 2.0.0. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/

Comment: the documentation refers to the fact that, for example, an editor is usually able to edit posts. So you might be tempted to check for the user being an editor to allow editing a post. That is wrong because maybe the capability was filtered so that user despite being an editor should not edit the post. And it can be the other way around, a subscriber might be allowed to edit posts or that specific post only. Checking capability ensure those expected results are respected.

Comment: That said, asking the question "Is this user an editor?" might still be a legitimate question. You should not ask it to determine if a user is allowed or not to do anything, but you might ask that question for some other reason. And if that's the case, then `current_user_can` with role name is just fine.

Comment: Regarding roles, yes, that's a public property you can rely on to be there, but `current_user_can` has filters, for example, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_has_cap/ or https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/map_meta_cap/. If a plugin or anything is using those filters to change what `current_user_can` returns, by directly checking roles property you're gonna miss the filters, and thus reducing the compatibility of your code with others code.

Answer (score 0):

For admin

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if (!in_array('administrator', $current_user->roles)) {
   //do something
}
```

For editor

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if (!in_array('editor', $current_user->roles)) {
      //do something
}
```

Please note that is only working if you want to check the roles of the current user, if you need to check for any other specific user, you need to use get_user_by (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/) or similar methods to retrieve the user you want to check

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php if( current_user_can('editor')) :
  echo "welcome";
elseif( current_user_can('member')) :
  echo "welcome";
else :
 wp_die("<h2>To view this page you must first <a href='". wp_login_url(get_permalink()) ."' title='Login'>log in</a></h2>");
endif;
?>
```

Comment: It would be great if you could explain as how it helps OP.

Comment: You can allow to see the page only "editor" or "member" you can post this code direct in generic-page.php

Comment: Please don't just drop code. Add comments and some explanation how this solves the askers problem.

Comment: So your answer is code duplication for each role?

Answer (score -3):

The correct answers to the above solution-question are by else programming basic:

```
if( current_user_can('administrator')) { 

<!-- only administrator will see this message -->

} else { 

        if( wp_get_current_user('editor')) {

<!-- only editor but no administrator will see this message -->

?>
<style type="text/css">#perhapsDIVremovalidentifier{
display:none;
</style>
}
<?php
} else {

<!-- the user is neither editor or administrator -->

}}
```

Brief: The administrator is found, but if we push editor the administrator is as well found. So we just let the administrator pass through and identify the editor only.

Remember you should always use this code to call that above to minimize cpu code usage:

```
if(is_user_logged_in()){}
```

Comment: That is exactly what is stated in the **question**, and what the author doesn't want.

Comment: I've added brief so that we have no misunderstanding. It was hard to follow the else rules I believe.