# How do I apply/target CSS to a specific user role or roles?

Tags: css, user-roles, front-end

How would I apply some front end CSS to a specific user role or roles?

Comment: See [this Q&A](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/131814/22534) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to add the roles into the **body class**, like here:

```
<body class=" ... role-administrator role-jedi role-knight ... ">
```

then you could try the following:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', function( $classes )
{
    if( is_user_logged_in() )
    {       
        $classes = array_merge( 
            (array) $classes,
            array_map( 
                function( $class )
                {
                    return 'role-' . $class;    // Here we prepend the 'role-' string
                }, 
                (array) wp_get_current_user()->roles 
            )
        );
    }
    return $classes;
} );
```