# How to restrict access to a page?

Tags: user-access

I am developing a page in WordPress. In `functions.php` file I have this:

```
function feed_add_notmusa() {
  add_feed('mypage', 'mypage_function');
}

function mypage_function() {
  get_template_part('/mypage');
}
```

But how can I restrict access to `/mypage` so only logged in users can access?

Could you please help me?

Comment: `get_template_part` doesn't take a URL path as a parameter, it takes a php template file name, the `/` is not needed. It will try to load `childtheme/mypage.php` and then `parenttheme/mypage.php` if it doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: [is_user_logged_in](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/)

```
function mypage_function() {
  if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    get_template_part('mypage');
  }else{
    echo 'please login for awesomeness';
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, it works ok, is there some way to restring for role to only admin can access to that page?

Comment: @skycomputer2 yes, but that's a new question, click "Ask Question" and include the solution here and what you need to do, and remember, we're all volunteers using our own personal time, the answer you get may not be in the form of copy pasteable code, but rather an explanation of what you would do

Comment: In general we use the [user_can](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/user_can) function & cross-reference with the [Roles_and_Capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) documentation to figure out what type of user we're dealing with... SO it's less user-level detection & more user-capability detection, because you can always add a custom user role with a custom set of abilities. But like @TomJNowell said, that would be a different question. Also, it helps greatly if you provide a... [Minimum Complete & Verifyable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Another post showing how to check roles with current_user_can: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131814/if-current-user-is-admin-or-editor