# Does jQuery/Ajax send cookies when using the rest API or do I need to somehow add them?

Tags: rest-api

I've run into an odd situation with [user capabilities](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/131816/109240). I have set up a rest endpoint on my local computer and am the super admin. The rest endpoint is called and the first thing it does is see if users can make posts (as this is what will happen with this call).

I used the following code:

```
    if(!current_user_can('publish_posts')){
        return array('reply'=>0,'error'=>'Forbidden','code'=>'403');
    }
```

I get back the Forbidden message. I know I am logged in as the form is hidden behind the exact same check.

Client side:

```
    var idata = {};
    idata['url']    = form.find('#attachment').val();
    idata['nOnce']  = form.find('#nOnce').val();
    // snip (etc.)
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: vars.path+'/post',
        data: JSON.stringify(idata),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            // snip
        },

        error: function (jqXHR, status) {
            // snip
        }
    });
```

Are cookies not sent with the AJAX call (I'm using jQuery client-side) and if not how do I make sure they send too?

How can I make sure that the user using my form is recognised as the current user?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#cookie-authentication

Comment: I've tried to follow everything in your link, @JacobPeattie, and got `wpApiSettings does not exist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not passing cookies with jQuery AJAX calls .. certainly not via Cross-domain access.

If you're going to use jQuery to pass data, you need to pass the current user ID and use `get_userdata($userid)` to determine whether the user has the correct capabilities.

Server side:

```
$jQuery_user = get_userdata($_POST['user_id']);
if(!user_can($jQuery_user,'publish_posts')){
   return array('reply'=>0,'error'=>'Forbidden','code'=>'403');
}
```

Client side:

```
// Be sure your form can somehow provide the currently logged in user id, hidden or otherwise.
var idata = {};
idata['url']    = form.find('#attachment').val();
idata['nOnce']  = form.find('#nOnce').val();
// if you have a nonce, you should be able to get user_id
iData['user_id'] = jQuery('#user_id').val(); 
// snip (etc.)
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: vars.path+'/post',
    data: JSON.stringify(idata),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        // snip
    },

    error: function (jqXHR, status) {
        // snip
    }
});
```