# How do I correctly setup an AJAX nonce for WordPress REST API?

Tags: rest-api

Following a link comment [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/348221/does-jquery-ajax-send-cookies-when-using-the-rest-api-or-do-i-need-to-somehow-ad) which led me to [these docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#cookie-authentication), I've tried to set up a nonce for user authentication.

I added:

```
wp_localize_script( 'wp-api', 'wpApiSettings', array(
    'root' => esc_url_raw( rest_url() ),
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' )
) );
```

to the if statement checking the user is logged in and able to do the things that will be asked in the REST call.

I also added:

```
        beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', wpApiSettings.nonce );
        },
```

to my api call jQuery class.

I got an error telling me wpApiSettings does not exist. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### First off..

(This info is for other readers who don't know yet about this.) There are two ways of how you can authenticate your REST API request:

- Using the standard [cookie authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#cookie-authentication)
- Using a plugin like [Application Passwords](https://wordpress.org/plugins/application-passwords/)

You can read more on the official REST API Handbook [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/), and this answer is for the standard cookie authentication, where the nonce should be ***sent either via a `GET/POST` query parameter named `_wpnonce` or a (custom HTTP) header named `X-WP-Nonce`***.

### Options for sending the cookie nonce

- Easy option: Append `_wpnonce` to the URL of the REST API endpoint. This works with `GET`, `POST`, etc. requests including JSON payloads.

  ```js
  jQuery.ajax({
      method: 'POST',

      // _wpnonce as a GET/$_GET query parameter
      url: '/path/to/endpoint?_wpnonce=<nonce>',

      data: { foo: 'bar', baz: 1 },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function ( data ) {
          console.log( data );
      },
  });
  ```
- Or add `_wpnonce` to the request *body*.

  ```js
  jQuery.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/path/to/endpoint',

      // _wpnonce as a POST/$_POST query parameter
      // but can be GET; see the `method` above which defaults to GET when not specified
      data: { foo: 'bar', baz: 1, _wpnonce: '<nonce>' },

      dataType: 'json',
      success: function ( data ) {
          console.log( data );
      },
  });
  ```
- Or particularly when sending JSON payload (just like the example code in [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/348221)): Add `X-WP-Nonce` to the request *headers*. This option also works well with `GET`, `POST`, etc. requests.

  ```js
  jQuery.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/path/to/endpoint',
      data: JSON.stringify( { foo: 'bar', baz: 1 } ), // sending a JSON-encoded string
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', // and a JSON Content-Type header

      // Send the nonce as part of the headers.
      beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', '<nonce>' );
      },

      dataType: 'json',
      success: function ( data ) {
          console.log( data );
      },
  });
  ```

### Now an example:

#### PHP part: (in your theme functions file or your plugin file)

```php
// Register a dummy REST API endpoint..
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'my_register_rest_routes' );
function my_register_rest_routes() {
    register_rest_route( 'my-plugin/v1', '/foo', [
        'methods'  => 'POST',
        'callback' => function ( $request ) {
            return [
                $request->get_params(),
                'Is user logged-in: ' . ( is_user_logged_in() ? 'Yes' : 'NO' ),
                'Can user publish_posts: ' . ( current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) ? 'Yes' : 'NO' )
            ];
        },
    ] );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts' );
function my_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Enqueue the script which makes the AJAX call to /wp-json/my-plugin/v1/foo.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', '/path/to/my-script.js', [ 'jquery' ] );

    // Register custom variables for the AJAX script.
    wp_localize_script( 'my-script', 'myScriptVars', [
        'root'  => esc_url_raw( rest_url() ),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ),
    ] );
}
```

**Notes:**

1. Remember that the first parameter for [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) — `my-script` in the above example — is exactly the same as the first parameter for [`wp_localize_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/). And that parameter is the script handle which is a unique slug as an identifier for the script you are enqueueing or localizing.
2. If those parameters don't match, then the script wouldn't be localized, and the JS object — `myScriptVars` in the above example — would be an `undefined` which could result in the error such as the one mentioned in the question ("*wpApiSettings does not exist*"). :)

#### JS part: (in `my-script.js` or whatever is the file name...)

Here, we add `_wpnonce` to the request *body*.

```js
jQuery.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: myScriptVars.root + 'my-plugin/v1/foo',
    data: { foo: 'bar', baz: 1, _wpnonce: myScriptVars.nonce },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function ( data ) {
        console.log( data );
    },
});
```

**Notes:**

The above and the other JS code in this answer uses jQuery's [`ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Ah, of course! I feel so foolish, of course the localisation must be done before headers. Doh. Great answer.

Comment: Note for the slowest among us (like me) the first param of `wp_localize_script` is the handle you registered your script with to enqueue it.

Comment: Thanks, I've added that to the answer.. :)