# Using WP-API and SSE not authenticating user ID

Tags: php, functions, wp-api, endpoints

I am using the `wp-api` to create a custom endpoint for my data:

```php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
        register_rest_route( 'mb/v1', '/sse/', array(
                'methods'   => 'get',
                'callback'  => 'mb_sse_data',
                'nonce'     => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' )
        ) );
} );

function mb_sse_data( $request ) {

    // headers to notify SSE
    header( "Content-Type: text/event-stream" );
    header( "Cache-Control: no-cache" );

    // set the variables
    $mb_setting_user_array = wp_get_current_user();

    // Get the current time on server
    $currentTime = date( "H:i:s", current_time('timestamp') );

    // data to return
    echo "data: current_time: " . $currentTime . "\n\n";
    echo "data: user_id: " . $mb_setting_user_array->ID . "\n\n";

    // Send it in a message
    flush();
}
```

And the javascript to call the SSE:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var source = new EventSource("wp-json/mb/v1/sse/");

    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log( event.data );
    };
};
```

Except when I check the output of the user ID I am still getting `0`. I understand that when authentication fails it will return the 0 value but I cant quote figure out how to make the above work so I can get the user ID.

Comment: See the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication). REST API requests are handled as unauthenticated unless the `X-WP-Nonce` header is set.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I read that first before posting, but I tried setting the header: `header( "X-WP-Nonce: " . wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ) );` but that didn't work. And the documentation only shows `beforeSend` which I cant see anything for the `EventSource`

Comment: @markb, you need to send the nonce header in the *request*. Or you may also send the nonce as a query string. See my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/348239) and you may also want to check [`window.fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). There's also the [`apiFetch`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-api-fetch/) API which utilizes `window.fetch()`.