# 403 error rest_'cookie_invalid_nonce' on API Request

Tags: plugin-development, rest-api, wp-api

I'm currently developing a Plugin in which I'm in need of retrieving information from a third-party plugin API.

To authenticate my users, I am trying to use the vanilla authentication via cookie as explained in the official documentation, but every request is refused with a 403 `rest_cookie_invalid_nonce` code.

I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong.

My code:

```
function makeRequest(){
  $url = 'https://xxxxxx.com.br/wp-json/wcfmmp/v1/orders/';
  $nonce = wp_create_nonce('wp_rest');
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'X-WP-Nonce:'. $nonce,
    'Content-Type: application/json',
  ));
  $result = curl_exec($curl);
  if(!$result) {
    die("Connection Failure");
  }
  curl_close($curl);
  return $result + var_dump($nonce);
}
```

Comment: I have trouble understanding what you are trying to do. Are sending a request from the same WordPress instance as the one that has the endpoint, or are these two different WordPress instances?

Comment: Yes, I am sending the request from the same WordPress instances

Comment: There is no authentication performed for internal requests.There's also no need for cURL, you can use WordPress' REST code:

```php
$request = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wcfmmp/v1/orders/' );
$response = rest_do_request( $request );
 var_dump( $response->get_data() );
```

Comment: Thank you I managed to do it with the help of your code.

Answer (score 1):

### Same site

As commented by [Fränk](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/17670/fr%C3%A4nk) request the same site it is better to use

```php
$request = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wcfmmp/v1/orders/' );
$response = rest_do_request( $request );
var_dump( $response->get_data() );
```

### Remote WP site

A great answer is written here for question [How do I correctly setup an AJAX nonce for WordPress REST API?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/348239)

Querying a remote site needs **Application password** as described in [Application Passwords: Integration Guide](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/)

When developing locally make sure to set `define('WP_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE', 'local');`

#### curl

This will fail as the `user` and `application password` is not known on given site.

```
USER=admin
APP_PASS="abcd EFGH 1234 ijkl MNOP 6789"
BASE64=`echo $USER:$APP_PASS | base64`

curl \
  --header "Accept: application/json" \
  --header "Authorization: Basic $BASE64" \
  https://wordpress.org/wp-json/wp/v2/
```