# How to hide Submit a deal button on redeal aka rehub theme for non-admins?

Tags: themes

What is the easiest way to hide "Submit a deal" button on redeal aka rehub theme for everyone but admin?

I am new to wordpress, not able to find anything in documentation of rehub

but I read on google to use this code but not sure how to ? is it going to break functionality when I will update theme in future ?

```
current_user_can('administrator')
```

Comment: This might help. [If the current user is an administrator or editor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131814/if-the-current-user-is-an-administrator-or-editor)

Comment: @Tiyo I am unable to understand where to put this code as I am very new to wordpress